# How to check date format in Spring WebFlow2

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

How to check date format in Spring WebFlow2.

I am trying to find some code that will work with Spring Webflow to check that the date the user entered is valid. I would think this is a easy check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a JavaScript regular expression on the client side and `java.text.DateFormat` on the server side:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd");
formatter.setLenient(false);
String dateAsString = request.getParameter("date");
Date date = formatter.parse(dateAsString); // throws an exception if the String is incorrectly formatted.
```

Comment: Yes, in your Controller, Action, Validator, or whatever way you are doing your server-side validation under SpringMVC and Spring WebFlow.